# How did Dragon's Lair foreshadow the story of Stranger Things 2?

Tags: analysis, stranger-things

In *Stranger Things*, playing Dungeons & Dragons foreshadowed the upcoming threat in season 1 and I expected the same from season 2, but I can't make out how the Dragon's Lair arcade game foreshadows any plot-line for the rest of the season. What am I missing here?

Comment: Dig duged does foreshadow the story of Stranger Things 2. ["A hero tasked with eliminating dangerous underground monsters who can tunnel through the dirt."](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2017-10-27/stranger-things-2-dig-dug/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Dragon's Lair game doesn't have to do with Will or the demogorgan this time, but with the love triangle of Max, Lucas and Dustin. We see Dustin playing this game while Lucas, Will and Mike watching. When Dustin loses this game, following conversation takes place.

> **Lucas:** You're not nimble though, but you'll get there one day. **But until then, princess Daphne is mine.**

Though, Lucas was referring to the video game, but it also predicts the outcome of the love triangle of Max, Lucas and Dustin.

[image]

[image]

[Source](http://www.dorkly.com/post/85442/stranger-things-season-2-details-easter-eggs)

Comment: this was also confirmed by the Duffer brothers on *Beyond Stranger Things*