# What is the parallel of Day of the Dead with Stranger things?

Tags: analysis, reference, stranger-things, day-of-the-dead

*Stranger Things* has a habit of foreshadowing the future in the form of games. In season one it was [Dungeons & Dragons](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80072/do-the-kids-from-stranger-things-have-any-analogues-to-the-dungeons-dragons-ga) and in season 2 it was [Dragon's Lair](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82357/how-did-dragons-lair-foreshadow-the-story-of-stranger-things-2), but in the first episode of season 3 they didn't play any game, and instead sneaked into a film with the help of Steve called *Day of the Dead*.

As with the format of the show, how does this film draw any parallels to the show? Or any foreshadowing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is one reference I could find in [this article](https://time.com/5610388/stranger-things-3-references/),

> Day of the Dead was **the third installment** in director George A. Romero’s iconic Night of the Living Dead series and was described by Romero as a **“tragedy about how a lack of human communication causes chaos and collapse even in this small little pie slice of society.”**
>
> This theme plays out later in Stranger Things season 3 when the three groups of Hawkins’ main players — El and her crew, the ice cream shop kids and the grown-ups — **fail to communicate what they’ve learned about the Russians and the mysterious Mind Flayer shadow monster until it’s almost too late.**

*Day of the Dead* is a third installment in the *Night of the Living Dead* series just like it is the third season of *Stranger Things*. We can also see a lack of communication among main characters like Romero described about his movie.

Comment: That sounds about right!

Answer (score 7):

> [Day of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_Dead_(1985_film)) is a 1985 American **zombie horror film** written and
>   directed by George A. Romero.

AJ's answer is pretty spot on in terms of overall theme, but there are couple of plot points to add that are in parallel, including *Day of the Dead* is also a **ZOMBIE** film and the Mind Flayer was taking others like Billy, Heather, Tom, etc and using them to get things done...

**Mild Spoilers About [Billy](https://strangerthings.fandom.com/wiki/Billy_Hargrove)**

> He then ran out of the mill and got back into his car, speeding away
>  in a panic. He stopped at a payphone to call 911, but as soon as the
>  phone picked up, he finds himself in the Upside Down, and a group of
>  people emerging from the fog, slowly walking towards him. He was
>  approached by a copy of himself, and asked what it wanted. **It told him
>  to "build what you see", referring to the zombie-like mob behind it**,
>  then suddenly he returned to the real world, clueless as to what
>  happened.

The Mind Flayer's over all goal was/is to destroy El, her friends, and then the world! *Day of the Dead* poses the same apocalyptic zombie threat, which in theory, may be more relevant to *Stranger Things* season 4.

In addition, even though they weren't "zombies", Steve and Robin get into a situation where they are heavily drugged, and ultimately not acting like themselves for a couple of episodes. And the Russian assassin character, Grigori, may have been a reference to an evil Terminator featured in *Terminator 2: Judgement Day*, who would stop at nothing to accomplish his goal. To clarify these two instances are depictions of these characters being somewhat "mindless" in nature, like zombies.

> In an underground facility in the Everglades housing scientists and
>   soldiers, the scientists are trying to find a solution to the zombie
>   pandemic, in exchange for the soldiers' protection.

There is also the prospect that *Day of Dead* featured scenes with scientists in underground military bunkers that broadly parallel itself with *Stranger Things* scientists and more specifically, The Russian's underground facility in season 3.